# How do I receive the system broadcast when Location has changed?

Tags: android

I wrote the code below, but it's not working. Can anybody help me? 
I just want to passively receive Location  changes.I want to run my application in background whenever it gets an Location changed system broadcast but here with this code its not displaying the log.

**Here is my Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver"
              android:enabled="true" >           
   <intent-filter>
        action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"               
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

**Not getting the Log**

```
     public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     public static final String PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED";  

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.getAction().equals(PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        Log.d("---------log--------", "Location Changed");
        myAction();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. "Not working" in which way?

Comment: I solved this issue.Of course its not easy to get system broadcast whenever there is a change in location, but  using CWAC LocationPoller https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll I can pass a alarm broadcast so that location can be found.

Answer (score 2):

To get the location updates, first implement the location listener interface.

```
public class LocationListeners implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("______", "location: " + loc.getTime() + " provider:" + loc.getProvider());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("_______", "disabled: " + provider);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("_______", "enable: " + provider);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("________", "privider: " + provider + " status changed:" 
            + String.valueOf(status) + " extras: " 
            + extras.getInt("satellites"));

}

}
```

Register for receiving location updates from the location manager using the desired provider. In your case Passive Provider.

```
locListener = new LocationListeners();
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
```

Whenever the device finds a new update location, it will give you a callback (since you register with the service to receive location updates). On location changed, provider changed and status changed, the callback methods from your implementation of the listener interface will be called.

Comment: What you coded is absolutely right but my problem was application is not getting notified whenever there is a change in location.

Comment: Location changes are not broadcasts. You have to implement the location listener interface and register it with the location service manager. You are trying to create a broadcast receiver which won't work. You get broadcasts only when the provider changes(GPS to Network or something else) and location is not passed. The location polling(from commons guy) will actively query for location at fixed intervals. This is required only if you need location at fixed intervals even if no else is asking for location. The passive listener will not actively query but will tell your app whenever ...contd..

Comment: some other app asks for location. If no app asks for location for very long time, you also won't get any update. Your question specifically mentioned that you need to passively receive location changes, hence my confusion.

Comment: Thanks for advice . I got fixed my issue.Of course its not easy to get system broadcast whenever there is a change in location, but using CWAC LocationPoller github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll I can pass a alarm broadcast so that location can be found